# Difference in terminology? JS Scope

Tags: javascript

I'm getting more in the OO side of JS now and less basic DOM manipulation and interaction parts. The one thing that is confusing as I'm brushing up on my books is the terminology of global, local, public, private variables.

From what I gather it seems that private/public is more borrowed from JAVA users crossing over but in fact they're simply global and local variables.

Am I wrong in assuming this?

Comment: Java and JavaScript have as much in common as car and carpet.

Comment: "private" and "public" are terms that come from [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) itself, not from Java. In Java you model privacy with `public`, `private` and `protected` *access modifier* keywords, in JavaScript you model it with variable scoping or property naming conventions.

Comment: I understand the differences in coding languages but I'm more trying to understand the public/private is just interchangeable terms when referring to global/local variables in JS.

Comment: In general terms...yes

Comment: In JS there are public and private properties, the problem is in the protected that doesn't exists. All depends of your scoping.

Comment: No, they're not interchangeable. Privacy is a *concept*, and does not necessarily have to do anything with variables. Also, most times we're concerned about the "public" *properties* of JS objects, not of variables.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Except there are no private properties in JS.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, there are.

Comment: I was guessing this was the same as the array difference that coders use, i.e var x = []; while some use var x = new array(). While I understand the concept of private and public are not the same. I've seen several refer to private var in JS and it looked to be just scoping into a local variable. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing additional declaration concepts in JS.

Answer (score 2):

Amaizing explanation [in this article](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) around this *question* P.S. ***Douglas Crockford***

***Public Constructor***

```
function Container(param) {
    this.member = param;
}
```

***Prototype***

```
Container.prototype.stamp = function (string) {
    return this.member + string;
}
```

***Private***

```
function Container(param) {
    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3; //private
    var that = this; // private
}

function Container(param) {

    function dec() {  // private method
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;

    this.service = function () {
        return dec() ? that.member : null;
    };
}
```

I hope this article will help you.

Thanks

Comment: I'll defintely give this a read! Thanks for the link. I'm moving off jQuery to React and Node for a company and have really beef up my stack.

Comment: That's the same answer as mine

Answer (score 1):

To understand the public and private variables in a Javascript object:

```js
var NewObject = function() {
  
  this.public = "that's public";
  var private = "that's private";
  
};

var instance = new NewObject();
console.log(instance.public); // that's public
console.log(instance.private); // undefined
```

Comment: The first one is not a variable. Please distinguish them propely from properties.

Comment: What's the first , then? If you said a property, properties are the variables in objects. Procedural is variable. Sorry for my english

Comment: To downvoter: in this code you'll see the permission access to the properties. It depends on the scope. Thank you for your downvote. You are smarter than all of us.

Comment: "*properties are the variables in objects*", uh, well, that's a hardly justifiable generalisation. Maybe there are similiarities between lexical environments and objects, but really there are too many differences between them. In JS, we care a lot about this terminology, mostly to not confuse people like the OP.

Comment: this.public is a public var. I don't see Bergi's point. The local var in the function seems to be sometimes termed private by others which is exactly what I thought.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to confuse the people. When I learn PHP the teacher tell us that properties in the objects are the procedural variables but different scopes and with permission access (private, public, protected). In javascript we can achieve that, but not protected

Comment: Bergi's point is that there's just a fundamental difference between a *variable* (something declared in a scope with a `var` statement) and a *property* of an object.  They're not the same thing.

Comment: You didn't, it's youtube that did that for me from JAVA guys teaching JS. @pointy my questions wasnt on language concept but terminology that I've seen used by JS instructional videos. I understand Begi point but I wasn't looking to invoke other language concepts on a local variable. Just getting clarifcation on loose terminology.

Comment: With my answer, you can have "private" and "public" items. Call them as you like. For puritans maybe are not the same, but in the practice you can use equal.

Comment: I will search where I learn this trick in javascript, because they call private and public variables too, it's not my invention

Comment: @Bergi your point on confusion was exactly my issue and thank you for clarifying. Lately the instructional craze online has gotten out of hand and when looking to get into something like Node loose terminology really confuses the situation when I hear public/private

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes, you're right about that, and people definitely use the terminology loosely and talk about "private" variables/properties. I think that's fine if it helps people understand, but on the other hand my experience tells me that a lot of JavaScript confusion stems from trying to map concepts from other languages (like Java or C++ or C#) over JavaScript constructs when it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @BrianEllis: Yeah, *variable* and *property* have quite well-defined meanings in JS, and when anyone uses these terms they should be accurate (Boo to those who don't). When in contrast you talk about "members" or "attributes" and "public/private", then we speak about concepts that are implemented through various patterns in the JS language, and it depends on the context how the author (speaker) applies the concept and to what; they have a quite loose meaning.

Comment: @Bergi totally understand now! and this makes a lot more sense. Now I know that private/public does have its place in JS in concept if someone is using these terms for simple lexical scoping it should be disregarded as its only correctly regarded as local/global in that situation. Where private/public is well more advanced in terms of structure but is still only a "loose" concept based on implementation not actually based on a strict coding method in JS. That was the confusion as the jAVA guy had me messed up as there is strict usage for private/public in their language.

Comment: I understand that, sorry for the confusion, but with this code he can achieve that